# Creating raster image using Shapefile in ENVI?

Tags: raster, shapefile, envi

I have shapefile containing polygon boundaries and want to change them as a raster image in ENVI 5.3. Although, this could easily be done in ArcMap or other GIS software, however, I will have to perform all operations in ENVI only.

I have searched ENVI toolbox to see if there is any availability but didn't succeed.

Comment: Are you refer this as "Clip" a raster applying to shapefile ?

Comment: It was about creating a raster image using available polygons exported from ArcGIS and imported in ENVI.

Comment: Do you want to rasterize the shapefile? What and from where the raster data (i.e. pixel values) should be and come from, respectively?

Comment: @AndreSilva the polygons had been created in ArcMap and Exported into ENVI 5.3 but there is currently no option to rasterize these polygons. Consequently, I have transformed my polygons using 'Polygons to Raster' tool available in ArcGIS.

Comment: I have more than 20 images of aviris data image and have a lat and long of the image.Which i exported the lat long data from excel in arc map and converted it into shape file.. I just want to know how to add the shape file into the image in ENVI software.Want to see where does the point lies on which image. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see that I am a bit late but it could be helpful to someone. It is actually possible to obtain a raster image of your shape file created in third party software using ENVI. One should use the ENVI classic. What you need to do is:

- open the raster image that was used as base to create the shape file;
- open the vector file, select the proper format. ENVI will ask to provide the right coordinate system (of course the raster image and the shape file should have the same system);
- Load the shape layer on the raster image;
- From the window 'vector parameters' -> File -> Export active layer to ROIs;
- Once you did this, you open the ROI tool and you will find all the polygons listed.
- From Basic Tools -> Region of interest -> ROI tool -> options -> Create class image from ROIs.

Definitely it will take more time than using ArcGis but if one has to use ENVI, this is the way.

Comment: It is not belated response. I will practically follow the steps to ascertain whether it works.

Comment: I am trying to perform this procedure in ENVI regular inspite of ENVI Classic. I can surmise that the objective can be achieved in ENVI 5.3 regular by converting shapefile into ROI and then classifying into continuous raster.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure If I understood your question here but have you looked at ENVI's tutorials or workflow here ?

Here is the link to their tutorial or workflow : http://www.harrisgeospatial.com/docs/tutorials.html

You may want to post your question on their ENVI related issues here
http://www.harrisgeospatial.com/Support/Forums.aspx
You may need to sign up and login to post your question there.

I've use ENVI in the past but have not done what you are asking for.

Comment: the polygons had been created in ArcMap and Exported into ENVI 5.3 but there is currently no option to rasterize these polygons. Consequently, I have transformed my polygons using 'Polygons to Raster' tool available in ArcGIS.

Comment: Read this http://www.harrisgeospatial.com/Support/Forums/tabid/184/forumid/13/postid/17856/scope/posts/Default.aspx